# I need to display this content: / ${item.type} | ${item.address} | ${item.rent} when the respective button is clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is from my codepen, so there is no doctype or boilerplate. I need help getting these buttons to work. when the button OMG Homes is clicked it will display informatino from the array ->This: ${item.type} | ${item.address} |  ${item.rent}
When the button Beach Homes is clicked it will display -> ${item.type} | ${item.address} |  ${item.rent}.
Based on the information provided in the js, and in the comments in the Js, how would I go about this.

```
<!--The HTML-->
<button id="omg-homes">OMG Homes</button>
<div id="omg-homes-results"></div>

<button id="beach-homes">Beach Homes</button>
<div id="beach-homes-results"></div>

<div id="all-homes"></div>
```

Below is the Java Script

```
//
// const suggestion = ['ded','eded','ede','e']
// Lakefront Beach Cabins OMG! National parks

const homes = [
    {
        type: 'Lakefront',
        image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',
        address: '1 Sample St',
        city: 'Boston',
        rent: 200
    },
    {
        type: 'Beach',
        image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',
        address: '1 James St',
        city: 'Boston',
        rent: 200
    },
    {
        type: 'Beach',
        image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',

        address: '1 Anon St',
        city: 'Boston',
        rent: 200
    },
    {
        type: 'National parks',
        image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',

        address: '1 Sample St',
        city: 'Boston',
        rent: 200
    },
  {
        type: 'National parks',
        image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',

        address: '1 Sample St',
        city: 'Boston',
        rent: 200
    },
   {
        type: 'National parks',
        image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',
        address: '1 Sample St',
        city: 'Boston',
        rent: 200
    },
    {
        type: 'OMG',
        image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',

        address: '1 Jerry St',
        city: 'Boston',
        rent: 200
    },
    {
        type: 'OMG',
        image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',
        address: '1 Josh St',
        city: 'Boston',
        rent: 200
    }
];

// const home1 =  {
//     type: 'Beach',
//     image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',
//
//     address: '1 Anon St',
//     city: 'Boston',
//     rent: 200
// };

// console.log(  home1.type === 'Beach'  );

/**
 * Finds beach homes
 *
 * @param item
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function getBeachHomes(item){
    if( item.type === 'Beach' ){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function getOMGHome(item){
    if(item.type === 'OMG'){
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
// Array.filter( fn )
const beachHomes = homes.filter( getBeachHomes  );
const omgHomes = homes.filter( getOMGHome );

// Array.forEach( fn )

//beachHomes.forEach( function(item){
     //console.log(`
           // ${item.type} | ${item.address} |  ${item.rent}
// `)
// } )

omgHomes.forEach(  (item) => {
//     console.log(`
//            ${item.type} | ${item.address} |  ${item.rent}
// `)
} )



document.getElementById("beach-homes").addEventListener("click", beachHomes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const homes = [
  {
    type: 'Lakefront',
    image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',
    address: '1 Sample St',
    city: 'Boston',
    rent: 200
  },
  {
    type: 'Beach',
    image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',
    address: '1 James St',
    city: 'Boston',
    rent: 200
  },
  {
    type: 'Beach',
    image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',

    address: '1 Anon St',
    city: 'Boston',
    rent: 200
  },
  {
    type: 'National parks',
    image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',

    address: '1 Sample St',
    city: 'Boston',
    rent: 200
  },
  {
    type: 'National parks',
    image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',

    address: '1 Sample St',
    city: 'Boston',
    rent: 200
  },
  {
    type: 'National parks',
    image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',
    address: '1 Sample St',
    city: 'Boston',
    rent: 200
  },
  {
    type: 'OMG',
    image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',

    address: '1 Jerry St',
    city: 'Boston',
    rent: 200
  },
  {
    type: 'OMG',
    image: 'https://picsum.photo/200?random=1',
    address: '1 Josh St',
    city: 'Boston',
    rent: 200
  }
];

const beachHomes = homes.filter(home=>home.type === "Beach")
const omgHomes = homes.filter(home=>home.type === "OMG")

const logHomes = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach(home=>console.log({type:home.type,address:home.address,rent:home.rent}))
}

const logBeach = () => {logHomes(beachHomes)}
const logOmg = ()=> {logHomes(omgHomes)}
```

```html
<button id="omg-homes" onclick="logOmg()">OMG Homes</button>
<div id="omg-homes-results"></div>

<button id="beach-homes" onclick="logBeach()">Beach Homes</button>
<div id="beach-homes-results"></div>

<div id="all-homes"></div>
```

There are more reusable ways to do it of course,for example you can write a script to append an `option` element inside a `select` element for every different type of home,and have a filter for every one,letting the data decide not hardcode it in your code.

This would be a good exercise,if you want i can show you,but you can try it yourself

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try more on my own

Comment: @Birdy if i have provided you a solution to your problem,you can always mark the answer as accepted! cheers

Comment: sorry, i'm still new to stack overflow. At the time I wanted to elaborate more on your response to my question. But have been busy as of late. I do want to say that your answer did help.